# Windows scheduled task unable to write to event log at startup

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I cannot get a log entry in to system or application logs if the below task runs as-is, at Startup (upon reboot and inspecting the logs) it will complete with success and write nothing to the application event log. If I run the task manually it writes to the application log just fine.

Powershell 5.1 on Windows 2019 Server:

```powershell
    # objective: log to windows event log at startup without requiring a login
    $command = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command { Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Application" -EventID 1 -Message "important system startup message" }'
    $action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument "-Command {$command}"
    $trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
    $settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8 -MultipleInstances IgnoreNew -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries
    $taskName = "Helpful Task Name"
    $description = "Task does helpful things"
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings -Description $description -User "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

UPDATE: As @Bender The Greatest pointed out, this has to do with invoking powershell from comspec, and the work here is about syntax reconciliation with escapes and quotes being the main offenders. Since there was no ready answer from the comments below I wanted to show the method I used with fixed code that includes an escape pattern for pushing local construction-time variables into the job data

```powershell
$script = "Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Application -EventID 1 -Message `"[$($env:COMPUTERNAME)\$($env:USERNAME)] important system startup message`""
$command = $script.replace('"','\"')
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command ""$command"""
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility Win8 -MultipleInstances IgnoreNew -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries
$taskName = "Helpful Task Name"
$description = "Task does helpful things"
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings -Description $description -User "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest -Force
```

Comment: Add `Start-Transcript C:\mytask.log -Append;` to the start of your schtask PowerShell command, and check that it actually ran and any output produced during the run.

Comment: That's a great suggestion, I tried it. Interestingly, no log file appears and the task still completes with success. 
    $command = '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command { Start-Transcript C:\task.log -Append;Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source "Application" -EventID 1 -Message "important system startup message" }'

Comment: OH. You can't provide a scriptblock to powershell like `powershell.exe -Command {command}` if you are invoking outside of powershell. It gets parsed as a literal string. The way you wrote this defines a scriptblock and exits.

Comment: Hey, you may want to consider adding your latest updated code as an answer instead of an edit to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `$action` definition like so:

```
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument "-Command ""$command"""
```

You cannot provide a `ScriptBlock` as an argument to `powershell -Command` *unless* you are invoking the `powershell` binary from within PowerShell itself. Instead, use a string as I've done above by using two double quotes (`"`) for a string argument instead of the curly-braces (`{}`) you wrapped around `$command`.

---

The reason external programs can't pass in a `ScriptBlock` is because outside of PowerShell, a `ScriptBlock` doesn't exist. When *Task Scheduler* executes this, it will parse this as a string, then PowerShell will process that parsed string. In this case, it will literally define the `ScriptBlock` and exit without running it because the curly braces get rendered in this case, which syntactically defines a `ScriptBlock` in PowerShell. You could theoretically prefix the `ScriptBlock` with the call-operator (`&`) and it should execute, but there's little point since you can simply use a string literal instead.

The `ScriptBlock` works inside PowerShell because inside PowerShell, it can do its own magic to ensure certain types are converted to strings *as it sees fit to* before execution. Instead of becoming a literal `{$command}` it will first render as a literal string *without the brackets* before the process fires off. The order of operations matters here and is why you can't use `ScriptBlocks` for `-Command` outside of PowerShell.

---

Keep in mind: as written your task will not work as you expect. However, once you fix the above problem, especially since you have the transcripting set up as per the question comments, this should give you the tools necessary to work through the remaining issues with your Scheduled Task definition.